# Parsing data: is img link slower then image from own server?

Tags: image, performance, parsing, hyperlink

I'm parsing data from other website, and question wether it's better to download images and show them on my own or just links to website images I parsed . Is the link to image by default slower then image from own source?

Couldn't find answer to the simple question. If question is discussable and doesn't belong here, someone comment down please in order to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Some rules of thumb:

1. Don't display content on your page which you 'source' from another site without the other sites permission. ('Share this' links provided by youtube are okay, directly linking to the .flv file of someones video from another site to display on yours is not).
2. Don't copy content from other domains onto your domain without their permission first (doing so would be a copyright violation).

So to answer your question: You should copy the content onto your domain/host, but only if they have given permission to allow this kind of use.

Edit: I am interpreting your question as "I am taking content from another website [and putting it on my own] and I am wondering if I should link directly to their content ( tags pointing to the other domain) or if I should download/copy the content to my website and have my server handle everything?"

The "technical" answer is "it depends on how good your host is compared to the other host when serving content to the average visitor". Compare a page run by Google vs. the same thing run on a home server behind a 56k modem. It matters if you have broadband, but if you're on a 33.3k modem it doesn't.

Comment: in this case big events website compared to DigitalOcean VPS